# Finding Percentage of marks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get percentage of marks submitted in form. But I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong in my code. I am taking marks from students and displaying their name and percentage. I am using form and input and submitting it to get the percentage in javascript.

```js
function getReport() {
    var name = document.forum.getElementById('name1').value;
    var eng = document.forum.getElementById('eng').value;
    var mat = document.forum.getElementById('mathss').value;
    var phy = document.forum.getElementById('physs').value;

    var totalmarks = eng + mat + phy;

    var percentage = (totalmarks / 3) * 100;

    document.getElementById('resname').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('getavg').innerHTML = percentage;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Student Result </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Student Result </h1>
        <form name="forum" onSubmit="getReport()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> Name:  <input type="text" id="name1" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong> Marks </strong> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> English  <input type="text" id="eng" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Maths  <input type="text" id="mathss" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Physics  <input type="text" id="physs" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="submit" id="subb"  value="SUBMIT"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <p id="resname"></p>
        <p id="getavg"></p>
        <script language="javascript" src="res.js" >  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few basic issues:

1) The form always posts back to the server (and thus destroys any changes made by the JavaScript), because you didn't prevent the default submit behaviour. `onsubmit="return getReport()"` and `return false;` at the end of the function will fix this.

2) `document.forum.getElementById` is not valid. You don't specify the name of the form here. IDs must be unique to the whole page, so it wouldn't be useful to do so anyway. `document.getElementById` is correct.

3) The values coming from the textboxes are strings initially. If you put them together using + you just get a string of all them together. This will make your maths go wrong. E.g. if you entered "3", "4" and "5" in the score boxes, then `eng + mat + phys` will resolve to `"3" + "4" + "5"`, and the result of that is `"345"` because they are all strings, so it just joins them together. This then makes the percentage equal to 11500, which is clearly nonsense. Instead you need to parse them as numbers using `parseInt()` (assuming they are always whole numbers), and then it will do (for example `3 + 4 + 5` instead, which of course equals `12`.

Here's a version which fixes all of those issues. These are all small details individually, which careful debugging can reveal quite easily.

```js
function getReport() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name1').value;
    var eng = parseInt(document.getElementById('eng').value);
    var mat = parseInt(document.getElementById('mathss').value);
    var phy = parseInt(document.getElementById('physs').value);

    var totalmarks = eng + mat + phy;
    console.log(totalmarks);

    var percentage = (totalmarks / 3) * 100;

    document.getElementById('resname').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('getavg').innerHTML = percentage;
    return false; //stop the form posting back
}
```

```html
<h1> Student Result </h1>
        <form name="forum" onsubmit="return getReport()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> Name:  <input type="text" id="name1" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong> Marks </strong> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> English  <input type="text" id="eng" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Maths  <input type="text" id="mathss" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Physics  <input type="text" id="physs" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="submit" id="subb"  value="SUBMIT"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <p id="resname"></p>
        <p id="getavg"></p>
```

Comment: Can you please tell how can i know these basic stuffs ? Should i solve more problems ? I read some theory from w3schools.

Comment: Yes, more study and above all more practice is by far the best way. Learn to use the browser's built in Developer Tools to help you inspect your page and debug your code. The browser vendors provide tutorials and documentation about it, as do 3rd parties. You can see error messages and also step through your code line by line to see exactly what the values of variables are and what paths the code takes at each stage. Also, pay close attention to the details in coding docs and lessons...small details can be very important in programming

Comment: Further, learn how to use Google to your advantage. In the modern era, when you're a beginner,  almost nothing you encounter will be new... someone will have had the problem before and asked about it. If you learn correct terminology for the things you are doing and ask questions in a generic way then you will find good results. And lastly...w3schools...its reputation is not good. Often there are mistakes or bad explanations. Try and find other tutorial sites, and use the official documentation and examples from MDN for instance, they are much higher quality, if a bit more technical.

Answer (score 0):

1. For get marks in javascript you don't need to submit your form.
2. wrong method for calculate percentage.
   Percentage=(Sum of marks/ obtainedTotal marks)×100

```js
function getReport()
        {

          var name = document.getElementById('name1').value;
          var eng = document.getElementById('eng').value;
          var mat = document.getElementById('mathss').value;
          var phy = document.getElementById('physs').value;

          var totalmarks = parseInt(eng) + parseInt(mat) + parseInt(phy) ;

           var average = (totalmarks/3)*100 ;
           var percentage = (totalmarks/300)*100 ;
          
          

          document.getElementById('resname').innerHTML = name ;
          document.getElementById('getavg').innerHTML = percentage ;

        }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

      <title> Student Result </title>

      </head>

      <body>

        <h1> Student Result </h1>
        <form name="forum" >

          <table>
            <tr>
              <td> Name:  <input type="text" id="name1" > </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> <strong> Marks </strong> </td>
                </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> English  <input type="text" id="eng" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td> Maths  <input type="text" id="mathss" > </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td> Physics  <input type="text" id="physs" > </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td> <input type="button" id="subb"  value="SUBMIT" onClick="return getReport()"> </td>
                      </tr>
            </table>



          </form>
          <p id="resname"></p>
          <p id="getavg"></p>

         

        </body>
    </html>
```

javascript code

```
function getReport()
    {

      var name = document.getElementById('name1').value;
      var eng = document.getElementById('eng').value;
      var mat = document.getElementById('mathss').value;
      var phy = document.getElementById('physs').value;

      var totalmarks = parseInt(eng) + parseInt(mat) + parseInt(phy) ;

       var average = (totalmarks/3)*100 ;
       var percentage = (totalmarks/300)*100 ;



      document.getElementById('resname').innerHTML = name ;
      document.getElementById('getavg').innerHTML = percentage ;

    }
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/tripathi_hhh/5h2boeq8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `document.forum.getElementById('name').value;`

Use simple `document.getElementById('name').value;` and for numbers you have to parse it for int for make calculation because you take input type as text which gave you string so you have to parse the string to int for cal.

And again your logic of calculating percentage is not accurate you have to do like this `(totelMarks * 100)/ maximum marks;`

Note: max marks from which you can get marks like in this perticuller case you have 3 subject so your max marks in 300.

Then delete the form submit onsubmit attribute from form and add replace the input type submit with the button and call onclick attribute on it like below

onclick="getReports()"

```js
function getReport() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name1').value;
    var eng = parseInt(document.getElementById('eng').value);
    var mat = parseInt(document.getElementById('mathss').value);
    var phy = parseInt(document.getElementById('physs').value);

    var totalmarks = eng + mat + phy;

    var percentage = (totalmarks *100) / 300;

    document.getElementById('resname').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('getavg').innerHTML = percentage;
}
```

```html
<form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> Name:  <input type="text" id="name1" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <strong> Marks </strong> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> English  <input type="text" id="eng" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Maths  <input type="text" id="mathss" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Physics  <input type="text" id="physs" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="Button" id="subb"value="SUBMIT" onclick="getReport()"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <p id="resname"></p>
        <p id="getavg"></p>
```